# What does reshape(60000, 28, 28, 1) mean?

Tags: python, numpy, conv-neural-network

I'm learning convolutional networks and python all at once.

I have a problem with the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(training_images, training_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
training_images=training_images.reshape(60000, 28, 28, 1)
```

I don't understand what `reshape(60000, 28, 28, 1)` means.

What are 60000 and 28 and 28 and 1?

I will get 60000 arrays of 28 columns by 28 rows... and the 1 is...

Comment: ...an empty dimension.

Comment: @NilsWerner and empty dimension?

Comment: Yes, imagine a matrix with a single column, of shape `(n, 1)`. There basically are no columns and you could represent it as a vector of shape `(n,)`. This means the last dimension is basically empty. Now just expand this concept to a 4 dimensional array and you have your answer

Comment: I think that the 1 means that they are images with only one colour channel.

Comment: If your data are images, then probably. But on a more abstract level, they're dimensions in an n-dimensional array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Think about it, how would you store 60k images 28 by 28 pixels if it was RGB?

For each pixel you would need 3 scalars (each for one channel), so it would be 60000x28x28**x3**.

And how many channels you need when the image is in greyscale? Just one, so it would be 60000x28x28**x1**

Of course, in case of one channel this could be simplified even more to 60000x28x28, but I would say the former approach is better because you give explicitly information about how many channels the image has and looks like some ML frameworks require that information to operate correctly.

Comment: Also, if you want your code to work with both colored and grayscale images, you should make sure to not leave out this "empty dimension".

Answer (score 2):

The reshape here is to put every image of the dataset into one tensor, fashion mnist dataset contains 60 000 images, each of size 28*28 pixels,  and if i recall the 1 is an empty dimension (since they are grayscale images) to match the input shape of your neural network.

Answer (score 1):

you can think of it as converting the `training_images` array to 4 dimensional array with sizes 60000, 28, 28, 1 for 0th to 3rd dimension. reshape rearranges the given array such that the size remains same i.e. 60000* 28*28*1 will be same as size of `training_images` before reshaping.